How to associate has_one relationships when using a generic id field?
I have an Activity model that will show a list of events that occurred (post created, event created, etc.).
In activity.rb, I have:
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :post
  has_one :event
end

For my Activity migration file, I have it set up like so:
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.string :action, null: false
      t.string :action_model, null: false
      t.string :action_model_id, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


I'm using a generic action_model_id for reusability between different models (instead of needing to store a field for every association, for example: post_id, event_id, etc).
How can I call activity.post or activity.event while keeping this generic?

This is called polymorphism and is supported by rails naturally as long as you adhere to convention. Docs. Also as you have it designed this would be a belongs_to (which is actually correct) not a has_one

has_one mean that the foreign key column is on the targets table - you only actually want it if you're creating a 1-1 association. belongs_to means that this models table references another table and is what you want. You always need a belongs_to as the inverse of a has_one/has_many.

Models changes
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :action_model, polymorphic :true
end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities, as: :action_model
end


class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities, as: :action_model
end

And you need to change migration
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.bigint :action_model_id, null: false
      t.string :action_model_type, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :activities, [:action_model_id, :action_model_type]
  end
end


For the migration you can use t.belongs_to :action_model, polymorphic: true this will add both columns and the index, plus it adds a nice consistency with the model setup
